# maven can not import jar in mac osx

Tags: java, maven

I build a common maven module named `push-common`. Another project need to import it. The one who use windows system can import it with maven dependency. However, the one who use Mac can't import it. The `pom.xml` configration as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.llh</groupId>
        <artifactId>push-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In actually, the `push-common-1.0.jar` even have been downloaded in local maven repository, but just can't import to project. By the way , the IDE is intellij idea 14.

Comment: it has nothing to do with IntelliJ IDEA, or any other Ide for that matter. Have you tried using command line maven? Also where is your POM details?

Comment: We need to know the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Build the project with mvn clean install, it will help you

Comment: also, try using command line or some shell in MAC. I am not a mac user so don't remember how to commandeer into console